# SSH Remote Port Forwarding not opening port

Tags: ssh, shell, ssh-tunnel, putty

I am trying a remote port forwarding on a remote server (linux) with this (local is windows):

putty.exe -ssh root@remote_host -R 55555:www.google.es:80

And the port is not open on the other side. When I try with a port that is already used on the other side (just to try) it doesn't throw any warning or error message. It is like the putty.exe command is ignoring the tunneling instruction...

Any idea on how to troubleshoot this?

Thanks!

Comment: Works for me (putty 0.70 on Win to CentOS) when the port is available, although it _displays_ no error when the port is not available. Try clicking on the icon at the top-left of the window and select Event Log, and scroll down, to see if there was an error.

Comment: Ah! I didn't know this event log. The message is "Remote por forwarding from PORT refused"...

Comment: You want port 55555 open on the remote_host and forwarding through your local computer to www.google.es:80 ?

Comment: Yes, I was just testing. The issue is solved, I had to configure de SSH server to allow TCP port forwarding (it was not enabled).